# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.helper'

Tags: python

I am a beginner with Python, When I try running PwnXss.py using (python pwnxss.py -u hostname) it returns with the following error, any suggestions greatly appreciated. **lib folder is in project folder and has the files needed.**

Current Python version 3.10.4

**Requirements:**

- BeautifulSoup4
- requests

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/XSS/PwnXSS/pwnxss.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lib.helper.helper import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.helper'
```

**Python code**

```
'''
PwnXSS - 2019/2020
This project was created by Andripwn with Pwn0sec team.
Copyright under the MIT license
'''
import argparse
from lib.helper.helper import *
from lib.helper.Log import *
from lib.core import *
from random import randint
from lib.crawler.crawler import *
epilog="""
Github: https://www.github.com/pwn0sec/PwnXSS
Version: 0.5 Final
"""
def check(getopt):
    payload=int(getopt.payload_level)
    if payload > 6 and getopt.payload is None:
        Log.info("Do you want use custom payload (Y/n)?")
        answer=input("> "+W) 
        if answer.lower().strip() == "y":
            Log.info("Write the XSS payload below")
            payload=input("> "+W)
        else:
            payload=core.generate(randint(1,6))
    
    else:
        payload=core.generate(payload)
            
    return payload if getopt.payload is None else getopt.payload
    
def start():
    parse=argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,usage="PwnXSS -u <target> [options]",epilog=epilog,add_help=False)
    
    pos_opt=parse.add_argument_group("Options")
    pos_opt.add_argument("--help",action="store_true",default=False,help="Show usage and help parameters")
    pos_opt.add_argument("-u",metavar="",help="Target url (e.g. http://testphp.vulnweb.com)")
    pos_opt.add_argument("--depth",metavar="",help="Depth web page to crawl. Default: 2",default=2)
    pos_opt.add_argument("--payload-level",metavar="",help="Level for payload Generator, 7 for custom payload. {1...6}. Default: 6",default=6)
    pos_opt.add_argument("--payload",metavar="",help="Load custom payload directly (e.g. <script>alert(2005)</script>)",default=None)
    pos_opt.add_argument("--method",metavar="",help="Method setting(s): \n\t0: GET\n\t1: POST\n\t2: GET and POST (default)",default=2,type=int)
    pos_opt.add_argument("--user-agent",metavar="",help="Request user agent (e.g. Chrome/2.1.1/...)",default=agent)
    pos_opt.add_argument("--single",metavar="",help="Single scan. No crawling just one address")
    pos_opt.add_argument("--proxy",default=None,metavar="",help="Set proxy (e.g. {'https':'https://10.10.1.10:1080'})")
    pos_opt.add_argument("--about",action="store_true",help="Print information about PwnXSS tool")
    pos_opt.add_argument("--cookie",help="Set cookie (e.g {'ID':'1094200543'})",default='''{"ID":"1094200543"}''',metavar="")
    
    getopt=parse.parse_args()
    print(logo)
    Log.info("Starting PwnXSS...")
    if getopt.u:
        core.main(getopt.u,getopt.proxy,getopt.user_agent,check(getopt),getopt.cookie,getopt.method)
        
        crawler.crawl(getopt.u,int(getopt.depth),getopt.proxy,getopt.user_agent,check(getopt),getopt.method,getopt.cookie)
        
    elif getopt.single:
        core.main(getopt.single,getopt.proxy,getopt.user_agent,check(getopt),getopt.cookie,getopt.method)
        
    elif getopt.about:
        print("""
***************
Project: PwnXSS
License: MIT
Author: Security Executions Code
Last updates: 2019 may 26
Note: Take your own RISK
****************
"""+epilog)
    else:
        parse.print_help()
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    start()
```

Comment: `lib.helper` didn't updated about 3 years. It is possible that it don't support python `3.10`. try to use `3.7` as recommended in Readme (PS I hope that you understand how to clone git repository)

Comment: Is there an \_\_init\_\_.py file in the `lib` directory?